# how to call a function in global scope inside another jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have function which executes in global scope. I want to call this function inside another function.

```
          $(function myFunction(){

            //does something 

           });
```

I want to call this function inside below jquery function

```
               $("#button").click(function(){

                  //does something

              myFunction();   //calling the above function

              });
```

thank you

Comment: what's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

This function does not execute in the global scope.  By adding `$(` you are actually calling `$(document).ready`.  Your code is the same as this:

```
$(document).ready(function myFunction(){
    /* ... */
```

If you want this function in the global scope, do this instead:

```
function myFunction(){

}

$(document).ready(myFunction);
```

Then it can simply be called from anywhere `myFunction()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/M6nQH/1/

---

Alternatively, you can put everything inside the same ready handler to keep things out of the global scope.

```
      $(function(){
          function myFunction(){

              //does something 

          }

          myFunction();  // call the function initially

          $("#button").click(function(){
              //does something

              myFunction();   //calling the above function
          });
      });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M6nQH/

Answer (score 0):

If the function is defined at global level you can call it `window.myFunction();`